# Hide content that only shown in specified page (beamer)

Tags: beamer, itemize

There is an `itemize` in my slide,  which is made of beamer, and three pages is generated for the three items.

What I want is that Content "**Another content (table) is here....**" for the item 1 is only shown in the first page. These content should be hidden in the 2nd and 3rd page.

So how can i reach this that? Thanks very much.

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Main findings from JRuby micro-indy benchmark }
  \begin{itemize}
     \item<1-> \textbf{Transformation Pattern} A small number of transformation patterns occur much more frequently than the others.  
      Another content (table) is here....

     \item<2-> \textbf{Instance Pattern} A large number of equivalencies (mean 28.9\%) exist among method handles.%, and a method handle has 7.4 equivalent method handles on average.

     \item<3-> \textbf{Instance Pattern} The distribution for the equivalent MHG set's size is uneven. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: put in in an `alt` : `\alt<1>{Here is your text}{\phantom{Here is the text in phantom... actually the same text as first}}`

Comment: In phantom just put the same text as your first to keep the place of the replaced with empty space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text should simply vanish after the first slide, I suggest using `\only<1>{your text}`. If you want I to become invisible (i.e. keep the space) you could do `\visible<1>{your text}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Main findings from JRuby micro-indy benchmark }
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
     \item \textbf{Transformation Pattern} A small number of transformation patterns occur much more frequently than the others.  
     \only<1>{Another content (table) is here....}

     \item \textbf{Instance Pattern} A large number of equivalencies (mean 28.9\%) exist among method handles.%, and a method handle has 7.4 equivalent method handles on average.

     \item \textbf{Instance Pattern} The distribution for the equivalent MHG set's size is uneven. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```